# How can i override plugin class function in wordpress functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to basically override a plugin class function in my Wordpress functions.php. I want to give access to the editor for the plugin settings. is there any way? because it has a constructor function. will be very thankful.

**Plugin code**

```
class BulkImport
{

    function __construct()
    {

        add_action("admin_menu", array($this, 'menu'));

    }

    function menu()
    {
        add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=wpdmpro', __( "Bulk Import &lsaquo; Download Manager" , "download-manager" ), __( "Bulk Import" , "download-manager" ), WPDM_MENU_ACCESS_CAP, 'importable-files', array($this, 'UI'));
    }
}
```

I want to replace the `WPDM_MENU_ACCESS_CAP` to `edit_pages`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, have you tried using an Admin Menu editor plugin such as [Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)? I don't have experience with it and thus can't vouch for it, but it seems well reviewed and managed.

---

**Edit**: If they are doing a capability check on the `UI` method, as well as the `admin_menu` hook, you may just be better off using the [`WP_Role::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/) to add the `WPDM_MENU_ACCESS_CAP` to the `editor` role. You would have to make sure that capability doesn't give them access to other things they shouldn't though. Based on the name of the constant, it *sounds* like it would be fine, but you'd need to do a cursory glance through the plugin to make sure.

---

Long answer: with WordPress, *generally* if things are done correctly, you rarely need to "override" plugin classes, class methods, or functions (though, sometimes you do). One of the **great** things about WordPress is its [Hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) system, specifically its [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

When a plugin uses [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and omits the third argument (`$priority`) gets set to `10` by default. The way priority works is that lower numbers get run on that hook first, so take the following:

```
add_action( 'some_hook', 'some_other_function' );
add_action( 'some_hook', 'some_function', 3 );
add_action( 'some_hook', 'func', 999 );
```

Despite the *order* these were written in, when `some_hook` runs on that request, `some_function` will run first (priority 3), then `some_other_function` (default priority of 10), and lastly `func` will run, with a priority of 999.

What this is nice for, is that `func` has access to modify or undo anything set in `some_function` and `some_other_function`.

Now your plugin has this line `add_action("admin_menu", array($this, 'menu'));`, which adds its own `menu` method to the [`admin_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_menu/) hook with a priority of `10`. This means you can write your *own function* and hook it to the `admin_menu` hook with a lower (higher number) priority, such as `11` or `99`. In that function, you can use the [`remove_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/) function to remove the page added by the plugin, and then use the [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) function to add it back in, but change any of the parameters! For instance:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_BulkImport_submenu', 11 );
function change_BulkImport_submenu(){
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=wpdmpro', 'importable-files' );
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=wpdmpro', __( "Bulk Import &lsaquo; Download Manager" , "download-manager" ), __( "Bulk Import" , "download-manager" ), 'edit_pages', 'importable-files', array('BulkImport', 'UI') );
}
```

Here's where it can be a bit complicated depending on *how* the plugin you're working with. in the last argument for `add_submenu_page`, you'll need to grab the globally instantiated class method, call it as a static method, or instantiate a new instance of the class and use the method there. I took a stab at what may be in there, but without seeing the plugin, I can't tell. For an example, I have a plugin where I have to mess with Elegant Theme's "Bloom" plugin, and in order to do it I call `global $et_bloom` and then `remove_action( 'wp_footer', [$et_bloom, 'display_flyin'] );` on the hook that there's a conflicy.

> You'll see posts about modifying the `global $menu, $submenu` (or `$GLOBALS['submenu']`), but those only work if you're *restricting* permissions, not *relaxing* them. This is because very early in the [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/#source) it checks  the return value for [`current_user_can($capability)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) and if the current user doesn't have it, it will be added to the global `$_wp_submenu_nopriv` and then the function returns `false` right there (so the item doesn't get added).

In general, I prefer the unhook/rehook method if possible, because it leaves a clearer trail of *what* you're doing, and why, and it works in both directions (restricting/relaxing). But, in the `admin_menu` hook, you have access to the `global $menu` and `global $submenu` variables, which you can modify before they get rendered to the page, but *after* the permissions have already been determined, it can get real ugly relaxing permissions on this hook, though restricting is nice and simple, here's a quick example:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function(){
    global $menu, $submenu;

    // Is the submenu I want in the page I want?
    if( isset($submenu['my-top-level-slug']) ){ 
        // Yes, we have an array of arrays (each submenu item = array)  
        foreach( $submenu['my-top-level-slug'] as $index => $submenu_array ){
            //var_dump( $index );
            // Search these arrays for my secondary slug
            $search = array_search('my-secondary-slug', $submenu_array );

            // This will return the submenu index if we found it, false if not
            if( $search != false ){
                // We found it! It's in this $index. Modify the [1]st element (permissions)
                $submenu['my-top-level-slug'][$index][1] = 'manage_options';

                // Stop processing this loop, we found what we came for.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}, 11 );
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the nice explanation, the menu is appearing, but, i can't access the page, saying, "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

Comment: Unfortunately that means that the plugin author has also added a user capability check to the `UI` function, so you'll need to look in there and see where to see if there's a place to modify it. You may also instead just be able to make use of the [`WP_Role::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/) method to add the `WPDM_MENU_ACCESS_CAP` capability to the editor role - provided that that capability doesn't open up access to other things. Based on the name of the constant, it _sounds_ like it would be fine though - but you'd have to look through and see

Answer (score 0):

More generally (but thanks to @XHynx's specific solution):

**functions.php**

```
remove_action("admin_menu", 'menu');
add_action("admin_menu", 'my_menu');

function my_menu(){
    /*copy the original function here and modify it */
}
```